# Mapbox error [HTTP] Unable to parse resourceUrl

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox

I'm trying to integrate map in my React Native app using Mapbox

I follow the [instructions](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps) for Android: creating access token, trying all [3 implementations](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/blob/main/android/install.md), but I keep getting this error

`Mapbox error [HTTP] Unable to parse resourceUrl mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11 {"level": "error", "message": "[HTTP] Unable to parse resourceUrl mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11", "tag": "Mbgl-HttpRequest"}`

And the map is completely black [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzeIf.png)

Does anyone know what causes the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using expo?

Comment: I have the exact same issue! Any updates on this?

Comment: also encountered this while using expo dev client

Answer (score 13):

I also had this issue. By exploring `GitHub` found a solution and finally made it work in my app. Before you define `MapboxGL.setAccessToken`, you need to put `MapboxGL.setWellKnownTileServer('Mapbox')`. Your code will look like:

```
MapboxGL.setWellKnownTileServer('Mapbox');
MapboxGL.setAccessToken("<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>");
```

Here is a reference to this issue https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/issues/1840

Comment: Thanks, I am using v10 and also get this error and did the same. 
```import Mapbox from '@rnmapbox/maps';
Mapbox.setWellKnownTileServer('Mapbox');```

Comment: @BilalYaqoob is Mapbox V10 Android SDK Documentation is also used in react native? Or there is Mapbox V10 documentation for react native?

Comment: mapbox has pretty good documentation, and Mapbox has community maintained SDK on GitHub and some docs of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! Just tried @Exoriri suggestion it on my dev build and worked like a charm. I was also getting an empty black box but this line seemed to solve it, wonder why it wasn't detected in the app.config.js. So yeah cheers from the Turbo Mono expo repo managed with pnpm ;P

```
MapboxGL.setWellKnownTileServer('Mapbox');
```

Did the trick.